# Debugging nodejs nbind c++ addons

Tags: c++, node.js, debugging, node-gyp

I'm currently trying to write a C++ NodeJS plugin using [nbind](https://github.com/charto/nbind) with the [universal example](https://github.com/charto/nbind-example-universal). Building and running the example works perfectly. Now I have two questions, first related to general debugging, the second related to my problem.

I added the [RF24](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24) lib. Constructing an RF24 object also works, but calling for example `getChannel()` or `printDetails()` function in Nodejs returns just

```
terminated called after throwing an instance of 'int'
npm ERR! Test failed. See above for more details
```

How am I able to get more details out of the errors, e.g. file and line number? I tried adding `node-gyp configure --debug build --debug` flags, but the build also only produces a *Release* folder.

My building command is the following, like suggested in the universal example.

```json
"build:native": "autogypi -r build && node-gyp -C build/native configure --debug build --debug && copyasm build/native dist"
```

I'm building on RPi Zero W (Arm v6). My current **binding.gyp** located in *./build/native* looks as follows

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "includes": [ "../auto.gypi" ],
      "sources": [
        "../../src/example.cpp",
        "../../libs/RF24-master/RF24.cpp",
        "../../libs/RF24-master/utility/RPi/bcm2835.cpp",
        "../../libs/RF24-master/utility/RPi/interrupt.cpp",
        "../../libs/RF24-master/utility/RPi/spi.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "../../src",
        "../../libs/RF24-master"
      ],
      "cflags": [
        "-std=c++11",
        "-fpermissive"
      ],
      "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-rtti" ] 
    }
  ],
  "includes": [
    "../auto-top.gypi"
  ]
}
```

The simplified program `example.cpp` looks like

```
#include "RF24.h"
#include "example.h"

Example::Example(uint16_t cePin, uint16_t spiBus): cePin(cePin), spiBus(spiBus) {
  this->radio = new RF24(cePin, spiBus);
}

uint8_t Example::getChannel() {
  return this->radio->getChannel();
}
```

And the corresponding header `example.h` looks like

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

class Example{
  uint8_t cePin = 22, spiBus = 0;
  RF24* radio;

  public:
    Example(uint16_t cePin, uint16_t spiBus);
    uint8_t getChannel();
};

#endif

#include "nbind/nbind.h"

NBIND_CLASS(Example) {
  construct<uint8_t, uint8_t>();
  method(getChannel);
}
```

So there are two questions

- General and more important: How do I get more comfortable debugging options for nbind c++ addons?
- More specific to my problem and related to RF24: Why does that error appear at each RF24 function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question I got a solution. NodeJS runs well with **gdb**. So doing

```
sudo gdb node
  > run myscript.js
```

prints the following a little more detailed error

```
Thread 1 "node" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb4c15ff8 in bcm2835_peri_read () from /usr/local/lib/librf24.so.1
```

If someone's around knowing what's going on or ideas on how to dig further, you're welcome. I used the RF24 script to make a shared library instead of building it with node-gyp. The error it produces is exactly the same.

EDIT: I build a workaround for testing purposes without nodejs first. It's working when giving the program root permissions. As it is a standalone rasbpi not connected to any network, root wouldn't be a problem. The nodejs addon requires root permissions because of SPI and GPIO.